# What is the way to create a map from 256 bit integers to values?

Tags: c++, data-storage

What is the way to create a map from 256 bit integers to values?

Is it `std::map<>`? or will `std::map<>` become slow as the data grows? If it is slow, what is faster?

Comment: Can you elaborate use case of this? If you try storing a large map to a row of multi_index table, it wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @conr2d Why do you assume that I try storing a large map to a row of multi_index table? I just want a large map from 256 bit integers to values. Anyway, I stopped this project.

Comment: Because storing data in a row is cheaper than adding new rows to multi_index. Every multi_index row costs additional RAM for indexing.

Comment: What is "storing data in a row"? Which row?

Comment: A row of eosio::multi_index. Won't you store instantiated map into persistent state? If you won't, forget about my answer.

Comment: @conr2d I was going to store instantiated map into persistent state. But I don't understand what you mean by a row of `eosio::multi_index`. Do you mean multiple `eosio::multi_index` objects? No, I mean just one `eosio::multi_index` object.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is too long to fit in comment, so leave here.

I came to know we are using different terms, but saying same things. eosio::multi_index is a table and you can add items (I called these 'rows'), but you said that you will make only one object. Then your code will be like this:

```
struct other {
  ...
};

struct [[eosio::table]] some {
  uint64_t id;
  std::map<checksum256,other> others; // checksum256 for 256-bit integer key

  uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
};

typedef eosio::multi_index<"some"_n, some> some_index;
```

If I understand you correctly, you will save all data into map (`others` above) in one row, not add multiple rows to multi_index. That is very inefficient when you save many data into one map. All data in that map need to be copied from internal db whenever you access this map.

```
struct [[eosio::table]] other {
  uint64_t id;
  checksum256 key;
  ...

  uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
  checksum256 secondary_key() const { return key; }
};

typedef eosio::multi_index<"other"_n,other,
  indexed_by<"secondary"_n, const_mem_fun<other, checksum256, &other::secondary_key>
> other_index;
```

The second example I attached shows a better way to save data with 256-bit integer key in eosio.

Comment: So, you mean `eosio::multi_index`  is more efficient than `std::map`? I don't understand why you refer to one row vs multiple rows, when `eosio::multi_index` is also one object (as you call it one row) just like `std::map`. Why do you call `std::map` one row but `eosio::multi_index` multiple rows?

Comment: Hmm, it seems you don't have much experience in EOS. eosio::multi_index is a handler of table. If it is just one object, why do you call `find()` to get specific object from it. Every field you declare works like column in DB table, every object you `emplace()` into multi_index works like row. BTW, all variables declared during transaction execution are freed after execution ends (not saved in persistent area), but the only data stored though multi_index will be preserved.